# Acrobat PDFMaker 11 for Word export to PDF and the persistance of metadata of 3rd Party templates

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, metadata

I'm in the Linux world.  If I take a 3rd party template in LibreOffice, for example, modify it and export that to a pdf, the metadata will show that `Nodak` is the author of the document, as Nodak is associated with the application that creates the pdf.

In the MS Word world, if someone took a 3rd party template, modified it, and then exported it to a pdf, does the third party name as author persist, or does the licence holder for the application which modified and exported become the author in the metadata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Word 2013, the author name will still follow the original document author. In Word, later editor are saved in `Last Modified By` field. Of course, I can just edit the authors manually.

Comment: So there is persistence into the exported pdf. Such as.. bob1-template --> sue-mod-contents --> export to pdf --> sue-report.pdf author Bob?

Comment: Yes, unless sue manually modify the author fields, the resulting PDF will only show bob as the author (there's no mention of sue as the last modifier in the PDF, not sure if it's PDF limitation or just Office specific)